# Implementing a nugget

Tags: c#, forms, nuget, file-watcher

I don't understand how to use the code for this nugget: [Myoddweb.Directorywatcher](https://github.com/FFMG/myoddweb.directorywatcher). After the nugget install I tried it like the example said:

```
// at the top:
using myoddweb.directorywatcher;


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var watch = new Watcher())
        {
            watch.Add(new Request(@"D:\Visual Studio\pictures", true));
            watch.OnAddedAsync += async (f, t) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("added");
            };
            watch.Start();
        }
    }
```

Nothing happens when I add a file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well I think because the watcher is disposed after invoking `Start`. You should move the the `watcher.Dispose()` to the Window close or unload event.

Comment: Thanks. I tried making a global variable like so: Watcher watch = new Watcher(); Then changed to using (watch). And watch.Dispose(); at close. But still no detection.

Comment: remove the using... Using disposes the object

Comment: Oh ok. But then I get some errors. I'll post a picture to make it clear how it looks: https://imgur.com/7YFjvwk

Comment: Please think a bit more and insert some facepalms here. I meant the using around `watcher`. Remove that... Not the using declarations in the file header.

Comment: Sorry my bad! It works now, thanks! But how to get what file is added I'm not sure about. I tried adding string FullName { get; } as a global variable, and then MessageBox.Show(FullName); under watch.OnAddedAsync. But it gives an empty messagebox.

Comment: The eventargs should have the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Much appreciated! =)